# Report error in CSV while streaming to the client

Tags: java, excel, csv, error-handling, chunked

I'm writing a server side code with Spring that produces a CSV output.
I don't know in advance how big CSV is going to be (I'm fetching source data from downstream in the process), so I'm writing CSV directly into HTTP response output stream line by line.

It appears that if process errors somewhere after some bytes have already been written to the response there is no way to handle that exception and it appears to the end user that CSV file is OK. The problem is that it isn't OK and it is incomplete due to an error.

I guess I have few options:

- use `Trailer` header and `Location` to redirect user on error. However, this seems to be not supported by any modern browser
- log error server side, but that doesn't give end user any feedback
- write entire response into temporarily file on the server and stream that file instead. This option has performance impact.
- write error message at the end of produced CSV stream, but it means end user will have to look for error message at the very end of the file and can potentially miss it

The end user is using MS Excel to open produced CSV file.

Is there any special character/byte I can write into CSV output in case of an error rendering it invalid and indicating an error to the end user?